# Django statement to save date and time when a button is clicked

Tags: python, django

I'm making a notes creator web application in django and I want to save the date and time when a note is created. (i.e. save date and time as soon as 'Submit' button is clicked.) What could be the django statement to do the same ?

Comment: this not how you ask a question. You should work on your code and put what have you done so far, here. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Community will definitely be glad to help you for right questions.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your model class, add this:
`created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`
It assigns current time when object is created.
You can retrieve that data in html file by using:

`{{ object.created_at }}`